# c# encrypt server but only can can decrypt on client

Tags: c#, security, encryption, voip

I would like to encrypt MP3 files on a server (recorded files), the only way to decrypt it may be on a client that have a client password/certificate.

It's important that none of the developers etc. can decrypt theese files.

How can it be done?

Comment: public/private key encryption. you encrypt using the public key (which anyone can have), and the decryption can only be done using the private key, which only the user knows.

Comment: Asymmetric encryption algorithms have certain limitations in terms of the data size that can be encrypted. Use a symmetric encryption algorithm for this purpose. Use RSA for encrypting the symmetric key and IV. The client should be able to decrypt the symmetric key and IV using their private keys. Keep your symmetric key very strong, since there should be only one key to have only one version of the encrypted MP3 file. For each client, encrypt this symmetric key with his public key and send it with the MP3 content then they can decrypt the symmetric key first and then the MP3

Comment: Is it possible to give me a sample in c#?

Comment: @user3437812 I'm sure somebody would if you offered to pay them.